# PyTorch RuntimeError

Tags: pytorch, gpu, remote-access

You can see from the picture below that I can access GPU.
[image]
But still, when I move tensor to GPU, there are Errors, like the picture shows.
[image]
What's wrong with it?

It is my first time to use the GPU in servers, I check if the GPU is available, if the coda version is right. These things are all right.
The results of `nvidia-smi`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njtd4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM577.png)

Comment: Perhaps you have set both environment variables in bash shell and in Python code. Or maybe your GPU is not working correctly, and you can check that by `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: @JohnHany I'm not sure about the set environment variables mean, what environment variables should I set? I also have used ``nvidia-smi`` check the GPU before, but it seems that they work. I'll add the results of ``nvidia-smi`` to my post.